# import CSV file into database using HTML and Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, mysqli

i try this code to import a CSV file into my database but i got this error : Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','', 'BD_Conference');


    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_conference (pid, name,  chairs,keynote, abstract, speaker, affiliation, ville, pays, salle, date, time, session, image_url) VALUES ('','$champs1','$champs2','$champs3','$champs4','$champs5','$champs6','$champs7','$champs8','$champs9','$champs10','$champs11','$champs12','$champs13')");

    $result = $db-> query($sql) ;
```

Comment: You already posted this http://stackoverflow.com/q/39308912/ and it was closed for the same reason; mixing MySQL APIs. Consult the link that both were closed with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check proper mysqli connection code should be

```
    $db= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'BD_Conference');

   $sql=("INSERT INTO tbl_conference (pid, name,  chairs,keynote, abstract, speaker, affiliation, ville, pays, salle, date, time, session, image_url) VALUES ('','$champs1','$champs2','$champs3','$champs4','$champs5','$champs6','$champs7','$champs8','$champs9','$champs10','$champs11','$champs12','$champs13')");

        $result =  mysqli_query($db,$sql) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

please use mysqli_query instead of  mysql_query. So the connection is opened using mysqli.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','', 'BD_Conference');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
}
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_conference (pid, name,  chairs,keynote, abstract, speaker, affiliation, ville, pays, salle, date, time, session, image_url) VALUES ('','$champs1','$champs2','$champs3','$champs4','$champs5','$champs6','$champs7','$champs8','$champs9','$champs10','$champs11','$champs12','$champs13')";

$result = $db->query($sql) ;
```